# Como faço para alterar as configurações do Blazor relacionadas ao head do site, como o idioma da página?

Tags: html, c#, .net, blazor

Estou me aventurando no mundo do Blazor, uma tecnologia que estou aprendendo recentemente. Para que minha experiência de aprendizado seja eficaz, sempre busco ter um controle completo sobre o que estou estudando. Ultimamente, tenho me dedicado a entender como alterar o idioma do meu site em um projeto Blazor. A ideia é fazer a transição do inglês para o português, tornando a experiência do usuário mais amigável e evitando que os navegadores solicitem a tradução constante do conteúdo para o português. No entanto, após dois dias de pesquisa, ainda não consegui encontrar a solução desejada. É frustrante ter uma página em português e, mesmo assim, o navegador continuar pedindo para traduzi-la. Estou em busca de orientações ou qualquer informação que possa me ajudar a resolver esse problema e, ao mesmo tempo, aprofundar meu conhecimento em Blazor.

Comment: isso esta documentado [aqui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Seja mais direto, direto na dúvida

Answer (score -3):

Uma das formas de se fazer isso é implementando a middleware da API. As requisições por padrão mandam o idioma do environment utilizado no proprio cabeçalho. Blazor é front-end e acredito que não faça esses tratamentos.